# How to show a checkbox outline when selecting a button

Tags: html, css

I want to show a button with checkbox outline when I select it like below. I'm not from a UI background. What can I do to achieve this?

[image]

```css
button:focus
{
    border: 3px solid #00aeef;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
Button <br>
With <br>
Checkbox <br>
Outline
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cnt = 0;

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("btn").selected = true;  
  document.getElementById('check').style.visibility='visible';
  cnt++
 
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('click',function(){
      
      if(cnt % 2 == 0)
      document.getElementById('check').style.visibility='hidden';
      })
```

```css
button:focus
{
    border: 3px solid #00aeef;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position:relative;
}


p{
position:absolute;
left:70px;
top:35px;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
Button <br>
With <br>
Checkbox <br>
Outline

</button>
<p id='check'>&#10003;</p>
```